# Aligning linechart with grouped-barchart using chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

The linechart datapoints are coming at the center of each label of grouped-barchart.

The input data will all be lists.

Plug-ins required to render the chart are "npm install chart.js", "npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels --save"

The code which I used is:

```
function draw_grouped_barchart(
  labels_data,
  billable_data,
  non_billable_data,
  total_data,
  bench_data
) {
  const max_y = Math.max(...total_data) * 1.25;
  var barChartData = {
    labels: labels_data,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "HC",
        backgroundColor: "#64218f",
        borderColor: "#64218f",
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: total_data,
        order: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Billable",
        backgroundColor: "#a83b8f",
        borderColor: "#a83b8f",
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: billable_data,
        order: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Non Billable",
        backgroundColor: "#ed8394",
        borderColor: "#ed8394",
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: non_billable_data,
        order: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Bench",
        backgroundColor: "#f8c7aa",
        borderColor: "#f8c7aa",
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: bench_data,
        order: 2,
      },
      {
        label: "Linear (HC)",
        data: total_data,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
        tension: 0.1,
        type: "line",
        order: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
  var chartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "end",
        align: "top",
        formatter: (value, context) =>
          context.datasetIndex !== 4 ? value : "",
        color: "#000000",
        font: {
          weight: "bold",
          size: 10,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        onClick: () => {
          return "";
        },
        position: "bottom",
        labels: {
          color: "#000000",
          font: {
            size: 10,
          },
          usePointStyle: true,
          generateLabels: (chart) => {
            let pointStyle = [];
            chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
              if (dataset.type === "line") {
                pointStyle.push("line");
              } else {
                pointStyle.push("rect");
              }
            });
            return chart.data.datasets.map((dataset, index) => ({
              text: dataset.label,
              fillStyle: dataset.backgroundColor,
              strokeStyle: dataset.borderColor,
              pointStyle: pointStyle[index],
            }));
          },
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
        text: "Allocations Projections (in FTE)",
      },
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        display: false,
        beginAtZero: true,
        max: max_y,
      },
      x: {
        display: true,
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
        ticks: {
          color: "#000000",
          font: {
            size: 10, //this change the font size
          },
        },
        border: {
          color: "#000000",
          width: 2,
          z: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  };
  Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
  $("#canvas").remove();
  $("#mycanvas").append(
    '<canvas class="w-100" id="canvas" height="350"></canvas>'
  );
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: barChartData,
    options: chartOptions,
  });
}
```

I have tried giving offset & transform. It didn't work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IxOu.png)

I want HC to be inline with linear HC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom plugin to move the points of line dataset to the same offset of the bar dataset.

See snippet:

```js
const plugin = {
  id: 'alignLine',
  beforeDraw(chart) {
    const metabar = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
    const metaline = chart.getDatasetMeta(2);
    const n = metabar.data.length;
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++) {
      const databar = metabar.data[i];
      const dataline = metaline.data[i];
      dataline.x = databar.x;
    }
  }
}
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [plugin],
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 14],
    }, {
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 3, 3, 10],
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      data: [16, 21, 5, 3, 10, 23,23],
    }],
  },
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```